# Not getting correct Path when Select Image from Gallery

Tags: java, android, image, gallery, photo

When I take an image by Camera, its works fine and I get the image path to save in SQLite database and can retrieve the path to show required image. But when I select an image from Gallery I don't get the correct path which I need to save in database for the further retrieve. I don't get image cause the path is incorrect when I save path in the database. So my question is - how can I get the correct absolute path of the gallery image?

```
  @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {

    Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);

    File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

    FileOutputStream fo;
    try {
        destination.createNewFile();
        fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(destination.getAbsolutePath());
    ivImage.setImageBitmap(bm);
    showImagepathET.setText(destination.getAbsolutePath());// This path will save in database
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {

    Bitmap bm=null;
    if (data != null) {
        try {
            bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), data.getData());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
    showImagepathET.setText(destination.getAbsolutePath());// This path will save in database
    ivImage.setImageBitmap(bm);
}
```

Here, I get the correct image to show in ImageView ivImage in both take an image by camera or gallery. But I don't get the path correctly when I pick an image from Gallery(works fine when I take camera Image) which I save in database for further path retrieve.

Comment: I know I have problem in line "File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");" But how i get gallery image selected Path ?

Comment: There is no "image selected Path".

Comment: "bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), data.getData());" is my image and works fine when i set in "ivImage.setImageBitmap(bm);"  Now how i can get this selected image path

Comment: There is no exact file that you wrote in select from gallery.

Comment: I said that I got the image correctly which means i have other methods for getting the image.. I asked for how i set or get this image path. at @EmreAktürk

Answer (score 1):

> how i can get this selected image path

For what feels like the 3,735th time, there is no "selected image path". You are getting a `Uri` back (`data.getData()`); a `Uri` does not have to point to a file. For example, `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44057912/not-getting-correct-path-when-select-image-from-gallery` is a `Uri`; it does not represent a file on the filesystem.

If you want a file, use [a file-picker library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/35?sort=created).

Comment: Aww sorry man, maybe I am absolutely failed to explain my problem or u didn't read my post correctly. But for again-- I am getting file properly no problem, but I need the absolute file path to save to database.... Just the path, not the image file.This decode my image(bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), data.getData());) This shows my required image(ivImage.setImageBitmap(bm);) with no problem

Comment: @user3210572: "I need the absolute file path" -- there is no absolute file path, because you do not have a file. You have a `Uri`. It points to content. That content does not have to exist as a file at all, let alone in a location you can access. As I wrote, if you want a file, use a file-picker library. Or, use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content, then copy the bytes off of that stream to some file that you control.

Comment: :" there is no absolute file path, because you do not have a file" ... If I do not have a file then how I am getting my Image from the gallery ? And also how I am setting my (that gallery image) image in "ImageView ivImage" ?

Comment: @user3210572: Under the covers, `getBitmap()` is using `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()`. No files are involved.

Comment: So there is no easy way to get the path .. i assume

Comment: @user3210572: Since there is no path, you are correct.

Comment: I am really sorry to disturb u , Actually i am new to android

Answer (score 0):

At last, I decided to do the same procedure what I did in Method "onCaptureImageResult(Intent data)". The image I get from the Gallery stored again to a directory.I know this is absolutely not the good procedure, but it solved my problem temporally until I get a good answer.

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {

    Bitmap bm=null;
    if (data != null) {
        try {
            bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), data.getData());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);

    File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

    FileOutputStream fo;
    try {
        destination.createNewFile();
        fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Bitmap bm1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(destination.getAbsolutePath());
    ivImage.setImageBitmap(bm1);
    String selectedImageUri = data.getData().getPath();
    showImagepathET.setText(destination.getAbsolutePath());

}
```